Conjecture: $x^4+1$ is never Wieferich prime
Related to this question and Alexander Kalmynin's answer.
For natural $n$ define $J(n)=(2^{n-1}-1) \bmod n^2$
and if $n$ is power of two define $J(2^n)=1$ (this is artificial, just to
avoid triviality and by $\bmod$ we mean take the smallest residue modulo $n^2$).
Prime $p$ is Wieferich prime iff $J(p)=0$.
The answer in the linked question use the doubly exponential
sequence of Fermat numbers and we are trying to generalize this.
Conjecture 1:  For even $n$ we have $J(n^2+1) < J(n^4+1)$ and
hence $J(n^4+1)>0$, so $n^4+1$ can't be Wieferich prime.
This holds for $n$ up to $10^6$ and several very large $n$.
Further we have:
Conjecture 2 For even $n$ large enough we have
$\frac{\log(J(n^4+1))}{\log{J(n^2+1)}} \sim 2$.

Q1 If Conjecture 1 is false, can we use this approach to
show primes of certain form are not Wieferich?


You may have this just by chance because of the range size of $J(n^4+1)$ is roughly the square of that for $J(n^2+1)$. If we assume that $2^{k-1}\bmod (k^2+1)$ is distributed randomly in the residues modulo $k^2+1$, then $J(n^4+1)\leq J(n^2+1)<(n^2+1)^2$ would happen with the probability $\lesssim \frac1{n^4}$. Since $\sum_n \frac1{n^4}$ converges, we should expect no more than a finite number of occurrences for $J(n^4+1)\leq J(n^2+1)$.

Considering that we strongly suspect but cannot prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^4 +1$ and that we also cannot prove that there are infinitely many non-Wieferich primes, this question seems likely to be very difficult.
